# Find out the number of cities and number of users belongs to a state using SQL JOIN

Tags: sql

i have 3 tables
user_1_j, city_1_j and state_1_j
[Click here for the 3 tables with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhCAx.png)

I find the state with the number of cities using this query,

```
select state_name as states, 
   count(city_name) as cities
from state_1_j s, 
     city_1_j ct
where  ct.state_id = s.state_id 
group by state_name;
```

[Result for the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coZqa.png)
And I also find the state with the number of users using this query,

```
select state_name as states,  
       count(username) as users
from state_1_j s,
 (select u_id as user_id,
         u_name as username,
         city_name as city,
         state_name as state
  from   user_1_j us, city_1_j ctt, state_1_j st
  where  st.state_id = ctt.state_id
  and    ctt.city_id = us.city_id) u

where  s.state_name = u.state
group by state_name;
```

[Result for the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gWVJ.png)
But I want the result to look like this,
[Click Here for the result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so4MV.png)

The below query running without any error, but the result is wrong.

```
select state_name as states, 
   count(city_name) as cities,
   count(username) as users
 from state_1_j s, 
 city_1_j ct,
 (select u_id as user_id,
         u_name as username,
         city_name as city,
         state_name as state
  from   user_1_j u, city_1_j ct, state_1_j s
  where  s.state_id = ct.state_id
  and    ct.city_id = u.city_id) u

where ct.state_id = s.state_id 
and   u.state = s.state_name
group by state_name;
```

Comment: what you are trying to do, what is your RDBMS ? Please ask question in a clear and specific method. Most people do not prefer images, instead format question with text. Are you giving us some knowledge with that image ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
select user.state_name, city_count, user_count
from (select state_name,count(u.city_id) user_count
from state_1_j s
inner join city_1_j c on s.state_id = c.state_id
inner join user_1_j u on u.city_id = c.city_id
group by state_name) user 
inner join 
(select s.state_name, count(c.city_id) city_count
 from state_1_j s
 inner join city_1_j c on s.state_id = c.state_id
 group by s.state_name) city
on user.state_name = city.state_name
```

Here is the fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e969f/24

Comment: wrong queryORA-00904: "U"."STATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 23

Comment: The query is running without any error, but the output is wrong

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. But one thing in SQL DEVELOPER where u use the alias 'user' is showing error, so I changed the alias name and now it's shows the correct output

Comment: Thats because User is the reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will help you.

```
DECLARE @State TABLE (STATE_ID INT,STATE_NAME VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @State SELECT 100,'State 1'
INSERT INTO @State SELECT 101,'State 2'

DECLARE @City TABLE (CITY_ID INT,CITY_NAME VARCHAR(50),STATE_ID INT)
INSERT INTO @City SELECT 10000,'city 1',100
INSERT INTO @City SELECT 10001,'city 2',100
INSERT INTO @City SELECT 10002,'city 3',100
INSERT INTO @City SELECT 10003,'city 4',101
INSERT INTO @City SELECT 10004,'city 5',101

DECLARE @User TABLE (USER_ID INT,USERNAME_NAME VARCHAR(50),CITY_ID INT)
INSERT INTO @User SELECT 1000,'User 1',10000
INSERT INTO @User SELECT 1001,'User 2',10001
INSERT INTO @User SELECT 1002,'User 3',10002
INSERT INTO @User SELECT 1003,'User 4',10000
INSERT INTO @User SELECT 1004,'User 5',10001
INSERT INTO @User SELECT 1005,'User 6',10004

select S.STATE_NAME,COUNT(DISTINCT C.CITY_ID) CITYCOUNT,COUNT(DISTINCT U.USER_ID)USERCOUNT from @State S 
LEFT join @City C on s.STATE_ID = C.STATE_ID
LEFT join @User U on U.CITY_ID = C.CITY_ID
GROUP BY S.STATE_NAME
```

[image: click to see the result]

Comment: ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 68

Comment: you can remove the ISNULL property.. that is added to put zero when there are no matching  records. but it is not needed.

Comment: ORA-00904: "U"."USER_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 72

Comment: Why you are using LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: Ok, I add a query to my question. The Query is running without any error but the output is wrong.

Comment: IF INNER JOIN IS USED INSTEAD OF LEFT JOIN THEN THOSE STATE HAVING NO USERS WILL NOT LIST IN THE RESULT.. THATS WHY I USED LEFT JOIN... WHEN WE USE LEFT JOIN THEN ALL STATE WILL RETURN AND IF NO DATA EXISTS FOR THAT STATE THEN OTHER COLUMNS WILL SHOW AS "0"

Comment: I write this script using MSSQL.